# Subset rows using date value inequality in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I want to subset a data (DATA) set I have using 2 different date variables -- START and END (which are in columns 2 and 3).
It has two parts. First, I want to exclude rows with missing values for these two variables. I have been using this:

```
!is.na(DATA[,2:3])
```

Then, I need to only include rows that have a value for START that is on or later than March 3, 1999 AND have a value for END before 2002. Both START and END variables are numeric and have a date class which has been previously formatted as (format='%d%b%Y')

Thanks!

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: The orignal data had every variable in START and END written in this way: 08JUN1987. I used as.Date(data$START,format='%d%b%Y') to convert it. It now prints out as 1987-06-08. So now I want to create a new variable where I drop any observations with missing values for START or END, and I only want to keep observations with START >= March 3, 1999 and END<2002.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ts)
data1<-window(data.ts, start=c(1993, 3,3), end=c(2002,12,31)) # you need to set the data as.ts

#or,

library(zoo)
data1<-data.z[as.Date(c("1993/3/3", "2002/12/31"))] # you need to set the data as .z
```